# Blazor Server project is not running after installing Blazorise.Snackbar component

Tags: blazorise

In my Blazor Server project I have been using blazorise controls. I started this project 3 months before. Now I wanted to use Blazorise.Snackbar component. So I ran nuget package command to install the component. Now my project is not running. It shows exception in the below lines of code in the Program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddBlazorise(options => { options.Immediate = false; })
    .AddBootstrap5Providers()
    .AddFontAwesomeIcons()
    .AddBlazoriseRichTextEdit();
```

The error message is:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'FocusTrap' in type
> 'Blazorise.Bootstrap5.Bootstrap5ClassProvider' from assembly
> 'Blazorise.Bootstrap5, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.'

My Current Packages version:
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Which is the version that you are using for each Blazorise nuget package?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I have uploaded the image showing the package version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the same version on all `Blazorise` packages to ensure that they are compatible with each other. Changing `Blazorise.Snackbar` version to `1.0.4` will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the issue I was getting. The issue arose when I tried adding Radzen to the project that previously had Blazorise. Adding the Radzen NuGet package had me install several other modules, and maybe some of them caused the modules that Blazorise relies on to get out of whack? The code compiled but I started getting the above exception. I took out Radzen and have now gotten the project to run again.


I will add Radzen one step at a time and hopefully get the project running again. We are evaluating choosing between Blazorise and Radzen, and maybe having them together